# Button Onclick not working in Explore browser

Tags: javascript, html

So I have this button

```html
<button title="Versions from selected testplan" class="btn-sm btn-primary" type="button" id="versionRVTMSearchDiv" onclick="autofillVersions('99792937V01.02.00.00001;99792913V01.02.00.00001')">&#10149;</button>
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="versionRVTM" name="versionRVTM"  value="'.$versionRVTM.'" placeholder="Chosen version..." readonly="readonly">
```

Which onclick call this function

```js
function autofillVersions(versionString) {
    var versionRVTM = document.getElementById("versionRVTM");
    versionRVTM.value = "";
    versionRVTM.value = versionString;
}
```

But I get these errors

[image]

It works in google chrome and Firefox

Do anyone know why the function wont work here?

Comment: If your talking internet explorer I'd say don't bother.

Comment: Show a message "internet explorer is not supported, go to edge". It is not supported anymore.

Comment: @JarneKompier well I never use it, but i know some of my older users like that browser... So might as well see what it takes to fix this error, so I dont get contacted why this dont work.

Comment: @SilvanBregy yes I could do that

Comment: @JarneKompier That may be true, but there's no reason this simple code shouldn't work there, just like it would have 30 years ago.

Comment: The second error doesn't seem to be related to this code.

Comment: Make sure you're not getting some other error before the definition of `autofillVersions`. That will prevent the function from being defined.

Comment: I don't think this code is the problem. Is there more on your page?

Comment: The code you've provided won't cause the `autofillVersions` is undefined error — either there are either other errors, you've overwriting it somewhere, or you're failing to load your script property. Nor will it cause the error bout `matches` since you don't use that word anywhere in the code you've shared. Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve] (use the live demo feature of the question editor marked with a `<>`)

Answer (score -2):

Very bad idea of calling a function in HTML, try

```
function autofillVersions(versionString) {
  var versionRVTM = document.getElementById("versionRVTM");
  versionRVTM.value = "";
  versionRVTM.value = versionString;
}

let version = "99792937V01.02.00.00001;99792913V01.02.00.00001";
let btnRVTM = document.getElementById("versionRVTMSearchDiv");
btnRVTM.onclick = function () {
  autofillVersions(version);
};
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <button
        title="Versions from selected testplan"
        class="btn-sm btn-primary"
        type="button"
        id="versionRVTMSearchDiv"
      >
        &#10149;
      </button>
      <input
        class="form-control"
        type="text"
        id="versionRVTM"
        name="versionRVTM"
        value="some value"
        placeholder="Chosen version..."
        readonly="readonly"
      />
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</html>
```

And it is important that all script files are written before closing tag body

Comment: `.onclick = autofillVersions(version);` would execute the function at this point, and then assign its return value (which it doesn't have) to the onclick attribute.

Comment: @CBroe Please cheack https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-bohr-0tb2yh?file=/index.js

Comment: While, if you had got the syntax correct, the first part of this would be good advice, it doesn't solve the problem. The second part of this is outdated, we have `defer` now.

Comment: @YevhenSynytsia — I've checked that URL, you still have the `onclick` **attribute** in the HTML.

Comment: @Quentin ckeack please this url https://0tb2yh.csb.app/

Comment: @YevhenSynytsia — Congratulations. You've fixed the problem in the sandbox. The problem still exists in your answer. It doesn't really address the **cause** of the original problem through. You're just shuffling deckchairs around on the Titanic.